# Allowing only client side app to access WEB API?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, javascript-framework

I want to make a better use of javascript frameworks in combination with ASP.NET MVC and since I am exposing WEB API to js frameworks it means that I am exposing them to the end user.

How can i protect WEB API to be used only by js framewoks and not to be directly accessed by clients. I think this is especially sensitive with CRUD operations. I do not want data to be inserted, deleted or updated without any security or restrictions.

If I put some user-password protection in WEB API, credentials would still have to be passed from client side in order to work, meaning the client would see it.

Is there a more standard way to do this?

Comment: You need some way to validate credentials a user is giving. Are users not logging in to your application to make changes to data?

Comment: @Prescott those changes could be done by user, anonymous user, could be done by app in the background..and all scenarios have in common that they all have web api fully exposed

Comment: @Prescott you could use certificates to validate at the IIS level

Comment: @edhedges there should be a bette solution. Especially for cases where you do not have root access.

Comment: This has always been a tough problem.  If you need anonymous access, you pretty much can't use client side javascript calls to a web server as everything is visible.  If there are solutions to this I'm very interested in hearing about them

Comment: @KyleGobel http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/12/securing-api-keys-in-a-client-side-javascript-app/